# Spring LDAP: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I'm using Spring LdapTemplate class to access ldap. I'm using a pool of ldap connections (PoolingContextSource class) to avoid creating connections all the time at runtime. However, I get this exception sometimes at my application:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: Connection reset; 
nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Connection reset [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]; 
Remaining name: 'ou=memberlist,ou=mygroups,o=mycompany.com'
```

(...)

My ldap classes are defined in the following xml

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="com.ibm.tp4.spring.ldap.CustomPoolingContextSource">
  <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSourceTarget" />
  <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
  <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="300000" />
  <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"/>
  <property name="dirContextValidator">
    <bean class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.validation.DefaultDirContextValidator" />
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="contextSourceTarget" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
  <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
  <property name="pooled" value="false" />
  <property name="anonymousReadOnly" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
  <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="myLdapResolver" class="com.ibm.tp4.model.service.user.MyLdapResolver">
  <constructor-arg ref="ldapTemplate" />
  <property name="ldapUserSearchBase" value="${ldap.user.search_base}" />
  <property name="ldapUserEmailAddressField" value="${ldap.user.email_address}" />
  <property name="ldapAttributes" value="${ldap.user.attributes}" />
</bean>
```

Has anyone experienced this problem and can suggest a solution?

I thought about using testOnReturn parameter in the pool properties instead of connection evictor used right now. When I do, I get the following warning when I run my web application in the browser:

```
WARN [org.springframework.ldap.pool.validation.DefaultDirContextValidator] - 
DirContext 'javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext@d150d15' failed validation with an 
exception.javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - Unwilling To Perform]; 
Remaining name: ''
```

and soon after, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to borrow DirContext from pool.; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not create a validated object, cause: ValidateObject failed  
org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.PoolingContextSource.getContext(PoolingContextSource.java:425)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the time out definition is way to low. There is a official Site from Oracle that will give you the possibility to figure out the source of the problem, very likely its not "Spring" its the Sun Ldap connector or your Ldap Server. Lots of people are against providing Links but i simply can't copy this page, maybe you try the "raw" statement on their site to see if it occurs too. It will bring you a step closer to your solution. (probably the ldap timeout config)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/readtimeout.html

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "1000");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:2001");

Server s = new Server();

try {

    // start the server
    s.start();

   // Create initial context
   DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
   System.out.println("LDAP Client: Connected to the Server");
        :
        :
} catch (NamingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 1) I'm using Spring LDAP, which is a wrapper around Java (JNDI) LDAP. I don't know exactly how to set this timeout using the Spring library.         2) I added a warning that shows up before the exception in my question, the problem seems an invalid operation, not a timeout.

Comment: What operation are you trying to perform?

Comment: I just set the Sprint LDAP property that tests if each LDAP connection it gets from the LDAP connection pool is valid before using it. Probably Spring send a simple dummy request to the LDAP server to validate the connection, but I don't know exactly which ldap operation this request performs. I'd have to read the framework code to figure it out.

Comment: Did you make sure you have the appropriate rights on the ldap? Remaining Name says '', do you search an empty string? If so can you try to add a few characters?

Comment: Irrelevant. This property has no default value, so there is no default read timeout, and if there was a read timeout it wouldn't cause a connection reset, it would cause a `SocketTimeoutException`, which would get wrapped in some LDAP exception. NB A read timeout of one second is an order of magnitude too short. It should be of the order of ten seconds to a minute.